# AVAudioPlayer volume controle on different songs

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer, volume

I am using AVAudioplayer to play 3 differents songs by pressing a button, using this following code:

```
-(IBAction)play
{
//Play sound1   
NSString *pathToMusicFile1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample1" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* mySong1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMusicFile1] error:NULL]; 
NSLog(@"Song1 Loaded");
mySong1.numberOfLoops = 0;
mySong1.volume = 1.0;
[mySong1 play];


    //Play sound2
NSString *pathToMusicFile2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample2" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* mySong2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMusicFile2] error:NULL]; 
NSLog(@"song2 Loaded");
mySong2.numberOfLoops = 0;
mySong2.volume = 1.0;
[mySong2 play];


    //Play sound3
NSString *pathToMusicFile3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample3" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* mySong3 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMusicFile3] error:NULL]; 
NSLog(@"song3 Loaded");
mySong3.numberOfLoops = 0;
mySong3.volume = 1.0;
[mySong3 play]; 

 }
```

That work fine but now i would like to use 3 more buttons to mute off the sound1, sound2 and sound 3.
I tried that :

```
-(IBAction)sound1
{
mySong1.volume = 0.0;

}


-(IBAction)sound2
{

mySong2.volume = 0.0;


}


-(IBAction)sound3
{

mySong3.volume = 0.0;

}
```

But I am getting errors "mySong1 undeclared" ! How can I manage to declare and have the possibility to mute OFF one of the sound by pressing button ?

Answer (score 0):

"mySong1 undeclared" is being presented because you are trying to access local pointers from one function in another function.  Basically, delete your pointers (AVAudioPlayer *) in the .m and just leave mySong3 (or 2 or 1) = //blah blah.  Then in the .h declare mysong1; 2; and 3; with pointers included.